# Understanding the proof of the characterization of quasicompact morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then in the proof of Proposition 10.1 in [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-8348-9722-0_11.pdf), it is shown that if $Y$ admits an affine open cover $\{V_i\}$ such that $f^{-1}(V_i)$ is quasicompact, then $f$ is quasicompact (as a morphism). But I do not quite understand how the proof works.

In particular, it says

> For $s \in \Gamma(V_i,\mathcal O_Y)$, denote its image in $\Gamma(U_{ij}, \mathcal O_X)$ by $t_j$. Then $f^{-1}(D_{V_i}(s))$ is the union of the $D_{U_{ij}}(t_j)$.

But why is it the case? I know for any ring homomorphism $\phi: B \to A$, $\operatorname{Spec} \phi$ pulls distinguished open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} B$ to distinguished open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, but this doesn't explain the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following setup:

- two sets $S,T$,
- a map of sets $f:S\to T$
- a collection of subsets $\{S_i\subset S\}_{i\in I}$ so that $\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i=S$,
- and a subset $T'\subset T$.

Let $f_i$ be the restriction of $f$ to $S_i$.

Would you agree that $f^{-1}(T')=\bigcup_{i\in I} f_i^{-1}(T')$? If so, then you're set, because this is exactly what happens in your proof, just with different names on the sets.